# specific alphabet repetition pattern match using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Suppose I have:

```
ttb_5_x1
tgg_5_x2
ttb_5_x5
tcc_8_x8
ccr_5_x4
```

I try to filter the lines based on the `t` alphabet in the begining. So lines starts with `tt` should be saved in a seperate file. Same for the lines start with `t`

Desired output should be:

```
ttb_5_x1
ttb_5_x5
```

and

```
tgg_5_x2
tcc_8_x8
```

I tried `awk '/^t/{print}'` or `awk '/^tt/{print}'` but it is not sensitive to 1 or 2 times repetition of `t` alphabet.

Comment: Can there also be other lines that don't begin with `t` at all? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes there are lines starting with other alphabets too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^tt/) {print > "outfile1"} else if ($0 ~ /^t/) {print > "outfile2"}}' file
```

If a line starts with `tt` (see `if($0 ~ /^tt/)`), it will be saved in *outfile1*, else, if the line starts with `t` (see `if ($0 ~ /^t/)`), it will be saved in *outfile2*. The order must be exactly this: first, check for `tt`, then for a single `t`.

*outfile1* contents:

```
ttb_5_x1
ttb_5_x5
```

*outfile2* contents:

```
tgg_5_x2
tcc_8_x8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I have lines that start with another alphabet as well.

Comment: @Apex See updated answer. You just need another check, and make sure they appear in this order: first, the check for `tt` at the start, and then for a `t` at the start

Comment: I just want to print lines start with ```tt``` separately from lines that start with ```t```. With youe else statement I think other lines that start with non (t) alphabet will be saved too.

Comment: @Apex Not now, I fixed the answer to fit your updated question.

Comment: As a matter of general interest - I just tested and found that the solution passing an input file through `grep` twice is seven times faster than this single application of `awk`. Details at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I also tested and found that running grep twice was over 2 times slower than a single application of awk. Details at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a simpler and shorter `awk` in a single `condition { action }` block:

```
awk 'match($0,/^t+/) {print > ("outfile" RLENGTH)}' file
```

Then check output:

```
cat outfile1
tgg_5_x2
tcc_8_x8

cat outfile2
ttb_5_x1
ttb_5_x5
```

Comment: what ```RLENGTH``` is doing exactly?

Comment: @Apex: `RLENGTH` is either `1` or `2` based on number of `t` at start.

Comment: I found ```RLENGTH``` really interesting. Just outta curiosity, I tried ```awk 'match($0,/^t+/) {print RSTART}'``` and this gives correct length numbers. But I wonder why ```awk '/^t+/{print RLENGTH}'``` can't help?

Comment: `RSTART` is match start position which will be `1` in both cases however `RLENGTH` is length of the matched string so that will be either `1` or `2` for OP's sample data.

Comment: Thought about strings that begin with three or more t’s?

Comment: @mathguy good point, the regexp should be `/^tt?/` or `/^t{1,2}/`.

Comment: But `/^tt?/` may also match `ttt` so if OP really wants to avoid matching more than 2 `t`s then use: `/^tt?($|[^t])/`

Comment: The point isn't to avoid printing lines that start with `ttt` it's to print them to the same output file as the other lines that start with `tt` since they also start with `tt`. So they'd go to `outfile2` instead of `outfile3`.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
$ cat file
ttb_5_x1
tgg_5_x2
abc_d_ef
ttb_5_x5
tcc_8_x8
$ awk '/^tt/ { print > "file1" } /^t[^t]/ { print > "file2" }' file
$ cat file1
ttb_5_x1
ttb_5_x5
$ cat file2
tgg_5_x2
tcc_8_x8
$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^t/{print > (/^tt/ ? "file2" : "file1")}' file
```

or maybe slightly faster since the above always does 2 regexp comparisons per line while the following only does 1 comparison for lines that start with `tt`:

```
awk '/^tt/{print > "file2"; next} /^t/{print > "file1"}' file
```

Here are the third-run timings for executing the above 2 scripts and all of the other solutions posted so far on a 10 million line file produced by duplicating the OPs input 2 million times using this script:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=2000000;i++) print}' file5 > file10m
```

ordered by speed of execution (slowest to fastest):

[Anubahva's awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821306/1745001):

```
$ time awk 'match($0,/^t+/) {print > ("anubhava_outfile" RLENGTH)}' file10m

real    0m8.184s
user    0m8.042s
sys 0m0.124s
```

[sexcpect's awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820896/1745001):

```
$ time awk '/^tt/ { print > "sexpect_file1" } /^t[^t]/ { print > "sexpect_file2" }' file10m

real    0m6.625s
user    0m6.480s
sys 0m0.128s
```

[mathguy's 2 greps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821186/1745001):

```
$ time { grep '^tt' file10m > grep_outfile1; grep -E '^t([^t]|$)' file10m > grep_outfile2; }

real    0m5.938s
user    0m5.812s
sys 0m0.111s
```

Eds awk 1:

```
$ time awk '/^t/{print > (/^tt/ ? "awk1_file2" : "awk1_file1")}' file10m

real    0m2.656s
user    0m2.535s
sys 0m0.110s
```

Eds awk 2:

```
$ time awk '/^tt/{print > "awk2_file2"; next} /^t/{print > "awk2_file1"}' file10m

real    0m2.604s
user    0m2.490s
sys 0m0.106s
```

[Wiktor's awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820810/1745001):

```
$ time awk '{if($0 ~ /^tt/) {print > "wiktor_outfile1"} else if ($0 ~ /^t/) {print > "wiktor_outfile2"}}' file10m

real    0m2.421s
user    0m2.315s
sys 0m0.096s
```

So, no surprises there.

The above were run on a MacBook Pro with 2.2Ghz 6-Core Intel Core i7 processor with these versions of the tools:

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

BSD awk was slower than GNU awk but BSD grep was faster than GNU grep so I used the timings from that fastest tools versions I have on my machine  since that's what you'd use if you cared about performance.

Comment: See EDIT at the bottom of my answer for speed comparisons.

Comment: I added my own speed comparisons to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I ran your tests on my gnu/Linux PC. I get slightly different ordering than yours (different times too, but that's not surprising). 2-grep solution is 4.95 seconds. Wiktor's awk solution is 2.15 seconds. Your first awk solution is at 1.78 seconds, so it's faster than Wiktor's. And your second awk solution is at 1.62 seconds, making it the fastest. Obviously the proportion of `t` rows, and of those, the proportion of `tt` rows, are highly significant. Another potentially significant thing is program versions. Mine are GNU awk 4.0.2 and GNU grep 2.20.

Comment: All of this raises a question for me though (and it pretty much answers it). I am re-learning Unix utilities almost 30 years after I learned them (having in the meantime worked in other fields - never an IT guy). When I grew up, awk was much slower than grep and sed. But the tests here show that even a single grep is slower than the awk to do the whole job. I should reconsider my old habit to "only use awk when I can't avoid it". I thought my tests confirmed that, but obviously your tests (which I was able to confirm) contradict it.

Comment: For typical invocations a single grep will usually be faster than a single awk because they both do regexp matching but then awk also goes on to do field splitting and populate variables like NF, $0, $1, etc. `sed` will typically be in between the two for similar reasons. But awk will still be pretty darn fast and if you need to do more than a simple `g/re/p` with **grep** or `s/old/new/` with **sed** then you should always use **awk** as the code you write will be some combination of clearer, simpler, faster, more robust, and/or more portable.

Comment: 30 years ago the awk you used was probably what is now known as old, broken awk (or just "old awk" - the default awk on Solaris) or the extremely poorly named "new awk", neither of which match up to modern awks like GNU awk in terms of performance or functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two passes of `grep`. It should be quite a bit faster than the `awk` solutions, even though it reads the input file twice. There are a few reasons for that: `awk` is a big machine, with much more overhead than `grep`. Also, writing alternatively to one file or the other means opening and closing those files repeatedly. With the solution below, we only write to each file once. (Unless I misunderstand how `awk` writes to those files - perhaps it opens them and then it keeps them open and available until `awk` completes?)

```
$ grep    '^tt'        file > outfile1
$ grep -E '^t([^t]|$)' file > outfile2
```

**EDIT**

I did some testing. I generated a file with 1.6 million lines, each consisting of exactly one string of 20 characters - a mix of lower-case ASCII letters and digits. Then I ran my solution (using two `grep` commands) against the accepted answer, using `awk`. Both solutions generated the same two output files - there are 960 strings that begin with `tt` and 46,160 strings that begin with a single `t` (followed by a character that is not `t`).

The "two times `grep`" solution takes 0.058 seconds on my machine. The `awk` solution takes 0.402 seconds. That's seven times longer.

Further comparisons: anubhava's `awk` answer (which puts strings which begin with three `t` in a different file, `outfile3`) takes 0.278 seconds, 4.8 times longer than the "two times `grep`" solution.

Ed Morton's solutions take 0.191 seconds (first solution - this is still 3.3 times longer than the two-`grep` solution) and 0.305 seconds (second solution, which is therefore slower, not faster, than the first).

For anyone who wants to repeat the tests: I used this command

```
$ head -c 4000000 /dev/random | tr -dc a-z0-9 | fold -w 20 | head -n 20000 > myfile
```

to generate 20,000 rows. Then I concatenated the file to itself (and then the result to itself) a few times to grow it to 1.6 million rows. About 1/36 of the rows begin with `t`, and of those, about 1/36 begin with two `t`.

Comment: I find your answer a good solution, but I have my doubts if reading twice and using 2 processes could be faster than the corresponding awk. The files, however, will remain open, not opened and closed repeatedly, [according to POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_10): "As long as the file remains open, subsequent calls in which expression evaluates to the same string value shall simply append output to the file. The file remains open until the close function is called".

Comment: @Quasímodo - I figured the same about the files remaining open, since redirection by `>` is not overwriting the file for each line. As to which is faster, only testing can tell (I think). Anyway, worth knowing. I may try a test myself when I have a few minutes.

Comment: awk will keep a dozen or so files open simultaneously.

Comment: @EdMorton [Gawk's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) says the number of open files are imposed by the operating system. That number is typically around 1000 files for Linux. So I'd think ~1000 files could stay open. What am I missing?

Comment: @Quasímodo In the past when running a non-gawk awk script that generates output files I've got a "too many open files" error after a dozen or so. The real limit is probably more like 15-20 but if you think a dozen you should be safe. For example, right now on MacOS with BSD awk: `$ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) print "" > ("file"i)}'` generated the error `/usr/bin/awk: file18 makes too many open files
 source line number 1` after generating files and 
`$ ls` outputs `file1 file10 file11 file12 file13 file14 file15 file16 file17 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9`

Comment: @Quasímodo - I had time to run the comparison. See the EDIT at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to run your command to generate the same input file I get `tr: Illegal byte sequence` as there's something in the `head` output that `tr` doesn't like. Are you sure you did third-run timing on each command to avoid cache-ing issues affecting it? The OPs input has 80% of the input lines start with `t` while yours has less than 3% - that would impact the timing for sure.

Comment: I added my own speed comparisons to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton - I ran each command a few times, what I posted are averages; but I didn't notice a significant difference between the first two runs and the others. Also, you say that the OP's input has 80% of the input lines start with `t`. I am just guessing that you don't know that, and that you are judging by the posted sample. The posted sample had 100% strings start with `t`, until I asked the OP about that so he added one more line to make testing more meaningful. Thank you for running your tests; I will repeat yours on my gnu/Linux system, I expect to confirm your findings.

Comment: When I said `The OPs input has 80% of the input lines start with t` of course I'm talking about the sample input they posted, my only assumption is that their sample input is representative of their real input. Thanks for re-running the timings! Having said that, we're doing all this and the OPs input file might be less than 100 lines long or something and they couldn't care less about how fast the code executes.

Comment: @EdMorton - and my point is that obviously his sample is not representative (other than perhaps by accident): initially he didn't have ANY rows start with anything but `t`, until I questioned that and he responded by adding just one more line. Another very important thing, if "most" lines begin with `t`, is how many begin with `tt`. In the sample data, it's "a lot of them"; timings may be different if only a small number of the `t` lines begin with `tt`. Re-running your tests right now, I'll reply under your Reply with my findings. Cheers!